# How to copy index from one Pandas df to another when certain condition is met in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

It's not that I haven't tried, but I couldn't find a solution.

This is the code:

```
from pandas_datareader import data
import pandas as pd

aapl = data.DataReader('AAPL', 'google', '2015-01-05') # Apple stock data
aaplclose=aapl['Close'] 
bricksize=2.5

aaplrenko=pd.DataFrame()
aaplrenko['Open']=0.0
aaplrenko['High']=0.0
aaplrenko['Low']=0.0
aaplrenko['Close']=0.0
aaplrenko.index.name='Date'

renko={'upperband':110.0, 'lowerband':107.5}   #Date is 2015-01-05

for i in aaplclose.index:
    if aaplclose[i] > renko['upperband']+bricksize:
         renko['upperband']+=bricksize
         renko['lowerband']+=bricksize
         aaplrenko=aaplrenko.append({'Open': renko['lowerband'], 'High': renko['upperband'], 'Low': renko['lowerband'], 'Close':renko['upperband']}, ignore_index=True)         
         
    elif aaplclose[i] < renko['lowerband']-bricksize:
         renko['upperband']-=bricksize
         renko['lowerband']-=bricksize
         aaplrenko=aaplrenko.append({'Open': renko['lowerband'], 'High': renko['upperband'], 'Low': renko['lowerband'], 'Close':renko['upperband']},ignore_index=True)
```

**Note**: I already have a dataframe with one column in it - aaplclose and an index with dates.

I have a condition in for loop, which if met will append new dataframe- aaplrenko

What I also want is on every iteration when True, it should append the new dataframe- aaplrenko with the index value as well.

Currently the index values are just numbers that increment.

In the last statement under If and Elif in for loop, if I don't keep ignore_index as True, I get an error.

[This is the error when I keep ignore_index as False](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9W4W.png)

Comment: Nowhere in this code do you append a value from `aaplclose` to the `aaplrenko` DataFrame. You simply iterate over the `aaplclose.index` and append the same `renko` values as many time as your `if` conditions are met.

Comment: Right! So basically I only want the date of the row of aaplclose to aaplrenko when  the condition for that iter is met, else it will move to 'elif' and there the same condition